# $GL(n,\mathbb R)/SL(n,\mathbb R)$ is isomophic to $\mathbb R^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be the group of all $n\times n$ matrices with real entries that are invertible. The operations of the group are matrix multiplication, matrix inversion, and identity matrix. Let $S$ be the set of $n\times n$ matrices with real entries and with determinant $1$. Let $R^\times$ denote the group of nonzero numbers with the operations of multiplication, multiplicative inverse, and $1$.

Prove that $G/S \cong R^{\times}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the determinant, in particular the fact that it is a homomorphism?

Comment: @AlexBecker, it would be very difficult for the OP to know what SL is otherwise...

Answer (score 5):

If you know that $\det:G\to \mathbb R^\times$ is a surjective homomorphism, then the exercise is easy. Observe that $\ker\det = S$ (since $1$ is the identity of $\mathbb R^\times$) and so by the first isomorphism theorem, $\mathbb R^\times\cong G/\ker \det = G/S$.

Comment: do I have to show that det:$G \rightarrow R^{x}$ is a onto homomorphism or can I just assume?

Comment: @Gamecocks99 That depends on whether it has been shown/assumed in your class?

Comment: $$\forall\,r\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;\det\begin{pmatrix}r&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&1&0&\ldots&0\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&  \ldots&\ldots\\0&0&\ldots&0&1\end{pmatrix}=r$$