# Did my understanding of $GL_n( \mathbb{K})/ SL_n( \mathbb{K})$ is correct? (basic understanding question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, solution-verification, soft-question

I am learning algebra by myself and i am trying to understand quotient group.
I have met this expression (without further explanations) $GL_n( \mathbb{K})/  SL_n( \mathbb{K})$ and I want to be sure that I understood it well.

#### Question: Did my understanding of $GL_n( \mathbb{K})/ SL_n( \mathbb{K})$ is correct?

1-
$GL_n( \mathbb{K})$ = This is the set of all $n \times n$ invertible matrices over a field $\mathbb{K}$. This is a group with the operation of matrix multiplication "$ \cdot$" .
$SL_n( \mathbb{K})$ = This is a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{K})$ consisting of all $n \times n$ matrices with a determinant equal to $1$.
$GL_n( \mathbb{K})/  SL_n( \mathbb{K})$ is by definition the set of all set of the form $\underline{\underline{G}} \cdot  SL_n( \mathbb{K}) $ with $\underline{\underline{G}} \in GL_n( \mathbb{K})$

2-
The quotient group $GL_n(\mathbb{K}) / SL_n(\mathbb{K})$ essentially classifies the elements of $GL_n(\mathbb{K})$ according to their determinant. Two matrices in $GL_n(\mathbb{K})$ are considered equivalent in this quotient group if their ratio is in $SL_n(\mathbb{K})$. In simpler terms, matrices are equivalent if they differ by a matrix whose determinant is 1.
Hence for exemple with $n=2$  we have that:
$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$ is equivalent to $\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$ since with $\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \in SL_n(\mathbb{K})$ we can writte $\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$
More basically we have with (for exemple) $\underline{\underline{G}}= \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$ that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$ is include in the subset $\underline{\underline{G}} \cdot  SL_n( \mathbb{K})$.

Is my understanding correct?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/361612/104041)

Comment: If you know the definition of the quotient group $A/B$ where $A$ is a group with $B$ one of its normal subgroup, then you can simply "plug in" $A=GL_n(K)$ and $B=SL_n(K)$. If you understand what a quotient group is in general, then I do not know why you are stuck by a particular, concrete example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to Shaun https://math.stackexchange.com/users/104041/shaun my understanding is correct.

PS: I just writte this answer in order to mark this topic as solved (I did not find an other way to do it).